# Do all wavelengths of light carries heat with them?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Do all wavelengths of light carries ‘heat’ (thermal radiation) with them? If yes then can you please tell me, “Which carries more heat, a single photon of gamma wave or a single photon of radio wave?

Comment: Light carries neither heat nor thermal radiation (also:  heat is not the same thing as thermal radiation).  This is a comment about semantics and definitions.  In *any* pursuit, communication of ideas requires that the sender and receiver of information agree on what the words mean.  As written, the answer to this question is "neither".   But we can try to guess what is meant (sometimes a dangerous thing to do).   Which results in a greater temperature increase?  (Under what conditions?)  Which carries more energy? (ditto)  Etc.   See the answer by @Annav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All photons transfer energy, so all photons can cause an object to heat up. Energy is related to frequency by the equation $E=hf$, where $h$ is Planck's constant. This means that a higher frequency photon carries more energy, so a gamma photon carries more energy than a radiowave photon.

Comment: When you say “heat up” do you mean raise the temperature of objects?

Comment: increase its internal energy

Comment: I see. What would be the increase in internal energy of an object due to interaction with a 60 Hz photon?

Comment: $E=hf=6.63 \times 10^{-34} \times 60 = 3.98 \times 10^{-32}J$.

Answer (score 1):

> Do all wavelengths of light carries ‘heat’ (thermal radiation) with them?

One needs a definition of "carries" . The wavelengths of classical electromagnetic waves that are considered thermal radiation are the infrared wavelengths [in the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum)

> If yes then can you please tell me, “Which carries more heat, a single photon of gamma wave or a single photon of radio wave?

Heat has no meaning in the quantum framework of photons.  [Heat](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/heat.html) is a thermodynamic variable, as well as temperature:

> [Heat may be defined](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/heat.html) as energy in transit from a high temperature object to a lower temperature object

In the table you can see the energy range  (on the right, the middle point of the interval )  of the gamma and the range of the radio wave, and the gamma has much more energy than the radio wave.  For this energy to contribute to heat an interaction with atoms/molecules/lattices is required that could contribute to macroscopic heat radiation.

Infrared energies are of the magnitude radiated by heated objects through the interactions of atoms/molecules/lattices, an are readily absorbed there.

Comment: So a single photon of any wavelength do not carry ‘heat’ or ‘thermal radiation’ with it, am i right? A single photon of any wavelength carries only energy and momentum with it. But isn’t heat a form of energy that we receive from the Sun directly through EM radiation OR do we experience heat because of atmospheric gases heats up by em radiation?

Comment: heat , like all classical variables, arises from a confluence of interactions of zillions of photons and other electromagnetic interactions of atoms/molecules/lattices when light impinges on matter.. Dependent on the frequency of light, energy can be transferred to matter increasing its temperature and therefore heat content, for temperature see this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html

Comment: I think, i was wrong saying, photons carries ‘heat’ or ‘thermal radiation’ with them. Actually i should say, photons carries energy with them which can ‘heat’ things up, am i right now?